# Assigning Text to Labels Dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am having a user enter in text through text field and then display it in a label in a separate ViewController.

Basically what I need to happen is

1 - Have the user enter in text

2 - The second ViewController creates and assigns the the text to a label

I need to the user to enter in multiple data entries and therefore need the labels to be created dynamically when the data is entered from the user.

I am passing my data through ViewControllers using delegates.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to create plus assign text to labels into other view controller?

Comment: have your firstViewController pass the data to the secondViewController in `prepareForSegue` and then set the `text` attribute of the desired label.

Comment: I am able to pass data through to a separate ViewController and display it, but I am want to enter multiple data entries from the same textfield and create a label for each entry in a separate ViewController as the user creates it.

Comment: Please, explain in a more detailed way your structure and what you want to achieve in a user-driven point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not consider `NSUserDefaults`? It can even pass the data across sessions.

Pass the data:

```
- (IBAction)saveLabel:(id)sender {
    NSArray *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DATA"];
    NSMutableArray *currentDataArray;
    if (data == nil) {
        currentDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    } else {
        currentDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data];
    }
    [currentDataArray addObject:self.textField.text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDataArray forKey:@"DATA"];
}
```

Process the data: (in another view controller)

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSArray *dataArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"DATA"];
    if (dataArray != nil) {
        int count = 0;
        for (NSString *text in dataArray) {
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200 + 40 * count, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
            label.text = text;
            [self.view addSubview:label];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo can be found at https://github.com/null09264/Demo-Stack

Answer (score 0):

**ViewController1**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Pass duration and time of day through to dataHistory
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"dataViewSegue"])
    {
        dataHistory *dataHistory = [segue destinationViewController];
        dataHistory.duration = self.durationTextField.text;
        dataHistory.timeOfDay = self.userChoice;
    }
}
```

**ViewController2**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if ([durationLabel.text  isEqual: @""])
    {
        [durationLabel setHidden:YES];
        [timeOfDayLabel setHidden:YES];
        [editButton setHidden:YES];
    }
    self.durationLabel.text = [self.duration description];
    self.timeOfDayLabel.text = [self.timeOfDay description];
}
```